# Git / strange behavior while getting an "unable to unlink files, permission denied"

Tags: git, version-control

Hard to describe what happens accurately.

Basically, I have 2 local/remote branch `A` and `B`; `B` deriving from `A` and ahead of it.

I made some works on `B`, and committed them. 
Thinking my commit was successful, I immediately ran: 
`git checkout A`

But it didn't place `HEAD` on `A`.

Indeed, I discovered some errors within the logs during the commit that I didn't notice at time:

`unable to unlink files, permission denied` for many files.
Solution was to give some permissions through `chmod` command.

The issue is that I ended up with a very very curious behavior: 
I lost my changes on `B` !

**Is it possible that the command 'git checkout A', while having some errors, acts as if it means: "get all `A`'s files and replace over `B` files, instead of MOVING from B branch to A branch, explaining why I got stale files (from last `A` commit) in `B`.**

Question is: Despite my lack of accuracy on the issue and the exact steps, what might be the issue causing `B` to revert all its changes ?...

Sorry if it isn't an OP very robust, but it would ensure me if someone tells me: "Oh I know what you've got, I already had this strange issue..."

This OP is clearly about figuring out what happened.

Comment: It doesn’t sound very likely that you lost your changes on B by running `chmod`. Are you sure you actually committed the changes? Check `git reflog` if you can see the commit you made.

Comment: I rephrased the OP with what I guess.

Comment: Yes, I committed at least one step before on B, a commit called "final 2.7 version", that is clearly ahead from `A` files. The issue is that the last commit (next to "final 2.7 version") contained `A`'s files versions ..., meaning without any changes from "final 2.7 version" commit. Clearly as if the global action was :  merge A to B and override all files.